# Class Population Counter. How to put the program all into one

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to develop a class population counter. The problem is       that when I run it 2 program come up. I wanted my program to be all in one. The counter keeps coming in a separate program and i can't transfer it into my actual program. How do I do this?

Here is my attached files, I am using Python

```
import pickle
import os.path
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk

population = 0 
def counter_label(label):
   population = 0
def count():
   global population
   population +=1
   label.config(text=str(population))
root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Population Count', command=count).pack()
root.mainloop()

class Class:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

class ClassPopulation:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Class population")

        self.firstnameVar = StringVar()
        self.lastnameVar = StringVar()

        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        Label(frame1, text = "First name").grid(row = 1,
            column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame1, textvariable = self.firstnameVar,
            width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        Label(frame2, text = "Last name").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        Entry(frame2, textvariable = self.lastnameVar,
          width = 40).grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        frame3 = Frame(window)
        frame3.pack()
        Button(frame3, text = "Add to classlist", 
            command = self.processAdd).grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        frame4 = Frame(window)
        frame4.pack()
        Label(frame4, text = "Population Count").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        frame5 = Frame(window)
        frame5.pack()
        Label(frame5, text = "0").grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)


        self.classList = self.loadClass()
        self.current = 0

        if len(self.classList) > 0:
            self.setClass()

    def saveClass(self):
        outfile = open("Population.dat", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.classList, outfile)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Class Population","New name registered")
        outfile.close()

    def loadClass(self):
        if not os.path.isfile("Population.dat"):
            return [] # Return an empty list
        try:
            infile = open("Population.dat", "rb")
            classList = pickle.load(infile)
        except EOFError:
            classList = []

        infile.close()
        return classList

    def processAdd(self):
        classList = Class(self.firstnameVar.get(), self.lastnameVar.get())
        self.classList.append(classList)
        self.saveClass()

    def setClass(self):
        self.firstnameVar.set(self.classList[self.current].firstname)
        self.lastnameVar.set(self.classList[self.current].lastname)


ClassPopulation()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think two windows are coming up is because the program runs `Tk()` twice - one `root = tk.Tk()` and another in `window = Tk()`. If you pass your `root` Tkinter instance to the class `ClassPopulation`, then it should show one single window.

[EDIT]

```
class Class: 
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname 
        self.lastname = lastname 

class ClassPopulation:
    def __init__(self, root_window): 
        window = self.root_window
        window.title("Class population")

population = 0

def counter_label(label):
    population = 0 

def count():
    global population 
    population +=1 

label.config(text=str(population)) 
root = Tk()
label = tk.Label(root) 
label.pack() 
ClassPopulation( root )
counter_label(label)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you able to explain in more detail in how do i do this, perhaps a structure of the coding

Comment: In `ClassPopulation`, edit `__init__( self )` to `def __init__( self, root_window )` and set `window=self.root_window`. And when calling `ClassPopulation`, pass `root` as `ClassPopulation( root )` - here `root` is this `root = Tk()`. Also try to keep the whole script together. It is a good programming practice.

Comment: So my coding looks like this now

Comment: population = 0 
def counter_label(label):
    population = 0
def count():
    global population
    population +=1
    label.config(text=str(population))
root = Tk()
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
counter_label(label)
root.mainloop()

class Class:
    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

class ClassPopulation(root):
    def __init__(self, root_window):
        window = self.root_window
        window.title("Class population")

Comment: Yep. This looks correct. Isn't this working ? By the way, you don't need to pass `root` in class definition. You can keep it like `class ClassPopulation():`. Rest of the code looks good!

Comment: I'm afraid no, error                                                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boa Pouv\Documents\Software Development\Python\ClassPopulationBackup.py", line 94, in <module>
    ClassPopulation()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root_window'